# multiplication of positive matrix and non negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume $A>0$ and $H\le0$ are two real matrices
I need to prove that $\mbox{trace}(AH)\le0$
I tried to diagonalize $A$ with an orthogonal matrix but I didn't get any results.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a matrix >0???????

Comment: @AbhraAbirKundu presumably, that $A$ is positive-definite and $H$ is non-positive.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @AlfonsoFernandez

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

== A positive (non-positive) definite matrix has all its eigenvalues positive (non-positive)

== The trace of a matrix is the sum of all its eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity)

Comment: I don't see a connection between the eigenvalues of A or H to these of AH

Comment: Extending the definition field to one that contains the eigenvalues of both matrices we can form their Jordan Canonical Form, and then their product's main diagonal is the product, up to order, of their respective eigenvalues...

Answer (score 0):

This kind of exercises are rather standard.

1. Let $B=\sqrt{A}$ be the unique positive definite square root of $A$. (That is, $A=B^2$ and $B>0$. Why does $B$ exist? Think orthogonal diagonalization.)
2. Show that $AH$ is similar to $BHB$ and hence they have the same traces.
3. Argue that $BHB\le0$ (here we need the positive definiteness of $B$) and hence $\operatorname{tr}(BHB)\le0$.

Comment: @user56714 We guarantee the existence of $\sqrt{A}$ if $A$ is ​​diagonalizable, which is not the case, is not it?